# Java: Alternative to passing "this" as constructor argument in order to reference creating object

Tags: java, constructor, this

I've spent a while thinking about different solutions that the one I went for as I've read around (I am not really experienced with Java yet) that using this for a constructor argument isn't usually a good practice.

What I am trying to do is to instantiate several objects of class JobGroupMod and for every JobGroupMod I have to create a certain number of JobMod objects that must be able to reference back the JobGroupMod objects in which they've been spawned from.

In order to accomplish that I am passing "this" to the JobMod constructor but, even if working, it didn't feel like proper designing.

```
public class JobGroupMod implements JobGroup {

    public JobGroupMod(Node n,Set<Job> clusterJobs){
        JobMod j=new JobMod(n,this);
    }
}
```

And now the JobMod class:

```
public class JobMod implements Job {
     public JobMod(Node n, JobGroup jg){
         setJobGroup(jg);
     }
}
```

My question is, is there a better way of solving this, or is my solution the suggested way?

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov Added in the question since it was pretty obvious what was being asked.

Comment: You should avoid passing `this` to another method from inside the constructor. The object is not fully constructed and you could end up with nasty problems that are VERY hard to diagnose (related to *visibility* and *multithreading*).

Comment: in multi threaded environment it's **a bug**. you are giving away reference to non fully constructed object

Comment: Non-static inner classes implicitly receive a reference to the instance of the surrounding class that created them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should try using a static factory method ([Effective Java link](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=1)).

This way you avoid passing `this` in a constructor call, which is highly ill-advised to say the least.
example code:

```
public class JobGroupMod implements JobGroup {

    public static JobGroupMod createModeMod(Node n, Set<Job> clusterJobs) {
        JobGroup jg = new JobGroupMod();
        JobMod j = new JobMod(n, jg);
        return jg;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the practical example; I implemented your code and it worked right away. The only change I did was making the CreateModemod method static.

Comment: Thanks about that obviously :-) fixed it

Comment: the problem occurs when someone uses reflection to call the constructor. Factory methods no longer work.

Answer (score 5):

As long as it remains the only thing you do in the `JobGroupMod` constructor is is *fairly* safe as long as you understand the ramifications. There's a lot of Java code in the real world that does this. It's still not something you really want to do, especially when you start talking about multithreading and concurrency.

The danger is passing `this` to something else before an object is fully constructed. If the constructor were to throw an exception after you did this and not fully construct, you could have a nasty problem. If another thread were to access the object you passed `this` to before it was fully constructed, you'd have a nasty problem.

What you'll often find in Java is people using a factory pattern to avoid this, an "init" type method, or dependency injection.

Comment: Even if it is the **last** thing in program order, there is no guarantee that the execution won't reorder memory operations, so it is not safe at all, in any position. (and, when discussing correctness, there's no such thing as *fairly safe*: the program is either correct or incorrect; it is correct if the specs guarantee it will always work, which is not the case if a referece to `this` escapes the constructor, in any position)

Comment: I would argue that in the real world (sadly) there's lots of code like the OPs and it doesn't actually happen. That being said, I'll edit a bit.

Comment: @BrunoReis: Who said that this class was supposed to be thread-safe? Most written classes aren't, and all the restrictions applying to thread-safety don't necessarily apply on non-thread-safe classes. I'm not saying it's a good idea to do that, but it's not so bad if the class is not a thread-safe class.

Comment: Do you know what it is *and* have you tested the exact platform that the OP is using, to know if this unspecified behavior will work in his favor? What about the exact platform every other StackOverflow reader will be using? It cannot possibly be done, so it is very dangerous to say that something is *fairly safe* when it is clearly wrong (ie, unspecified).

Comment: JB: The point is: if we don't know whether this class is going to be used in a MT environment, one must assume the worst case to analyze its correctness. Futhermore, future readers might try to use this in a MT env., and won't be aware that there's a nasty bug.

Comment: @BrunoReis: I disagree. By this logic, we should make every method modifying two fields synchronized by default in every answer we write, in case the class is supposed to be thread-safe. In 99% of the cases, we write non-threadsafe classes. I have no problem explaining that IF the class must be thread-safe, THEN escaping `this` from the constructor must never be done, but assuming thread-safety requirements by default is just unrealistic.

Comment: JB: well, even if you disagree, the class still presents a bug, and this should be pointed out. Probably the writer of the answer had no idea about it, the OP neither, and most people who will read this answer (and copy-and-paste code, since some "high rep" answer says it is ok - while it is not) won't either, and if you simply "promote" something that is broken, you are promoting broken code.

Comment: Finally, "good practices" are there to help people write *strictly* correct code (in opposition to *fairly* correct code) even if they don't fully understand what's going on. Call it a *good practice*: do not let a reference to `this` escape the constructor.

Comment: That I can agree with. But I find it useful to know *why* a practice is good or bad, and *when* not following it is just bad design, or makes the code incorrect. To me, if the class is not meant to be thread-safe, it's bad design, but it's not a bug. If the class is meant to be thread-safe, then it's a bug. Stating that in an answer is more useful than just saying: "you should never do that" without explaining why and the consequences.

Comment: @BrunoReis - While I get where you're coming from, I live in the real world and am not overly pedantic. You'll note in my original answer I noted you didn't really want to do it, why, and what people do to avoid it. I didn't even touch on multithreading because much like JB says, if that were the case we'd need to edit about half (being kind) the questions on SO. Perhaps if you wanted to stress all these points *you* should have posted an answer.

Comment: Brian: What exactly do you mean? What world do you think I live in? I'm pretty sure you didn't get things right -- once more. Anyways, what's the purpose of trying to defend so vehemently something that is wrong, when you know it is wrong, and when you know how to make it correct? Don't want (or know how) to explain why it is wrong? Ok, don't mention MT, just says that it is wrong. And yes, it would be an unrealist job to fix all the wrong answers here in SO -- even if we start by fixing only accepted wrong answers...

Answer (score 0):

Generally there is no magic. You can either pass parameter via constructor or initalize it later using setter/init method etc.

If your class `JobMod` needs reference to `JobGroupMod` and has nothing to do without it pass it using constructor. If sometimes it can stand without it create `init()` method or setter that can initialize this reference.

BTW sometimes you have to create both parameterized and default constructor: first for regular programmatic usage, second if you are using XML, JSON or other serialization that is going easier for bean-like classes. In this case at least create javadoc that explains that default constructor should not be used directly.