# andEngine: Why the touch event doesn't work?

Tags: java, android, touch, andengine, game-physics

I'm learning how to use box2d and andEngine. I am trying to make my sprite with body move. I made it work before when I coded everything in onCreateScene, but now I want to make a separate class for my sprite. So right now my onCreateScene looks like this:

```
    mScene = new Scene();
    mScene.registerUpdateHandler(physicsWorld);
    Kapsel kapselBialy = new Kapsel(100, 100, 100, 100,     ResourceManager.getInstance().mBialyKapselRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager(), physicsWorld);
    mScene.registerTouchArea(kapselBialy);
    mScene.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);
    mScene.attachChild(kapselBialy);
    pOnCreateSceneCallback.onCreateSceneFinished(mScene);
```

And my Kapsel class looks like this:

```
public class Kapsel extends Sprite  {

private Body body;


public Kapsel(float pX, float pY, float pWidth, float pHeight,
        ITextureRegion pTextureRegion,
        VertexBufferObjectManager pVertexBufferObjectManager, PhysicsWorld physicsWorld) {
    super(pX, pY, pWidth, pHeight, pTextureRegion, pVertexBufferObjectManager);
    createPhysics(physicsWorld);


}
//definiowanie zahchowań po dotyku
@Override
public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY){

    if(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_UP){

        body.setLinearVelocity(-((pSceneTouchEvent.getX()/32 - body.getPosition().x) * 10), -((pSceneTouchEvent.getY()/32 - body.getPosition().y) * 10));

    }

    return true;
}

//Tworzenie ciała i fizyki dla kapsla
private void createPhysics(PhysicsWorld physicsWorld){
    body = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(physicsWorld, this, BodyType.DynamicBody, PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f));
    physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(this, body, true, true));
}
}
```

My sprite shows properly, but the touch event doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the problem was that in `onPopulateScene()` i did not put `pOnPopulateSceneCallback.onPopulateSceneFinished();`. Turns out that even if you define your scene and sprites in onCreateScene() it is still needed t put that in onPopulateScene(). Still I will keep in mind that I should not put 'this' in constructor (even if it works :) ).

Answer (score 1):

In `Kapsel` you are referencing `this` from within the constructor. This happens since the constructor calls `createPhysics` which in turn calls `physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(this, body, true, true))`. Note how `this` is referenced as it is passed to the `PhysicsConnector` constructor.

Referencing `this` that way in the constructor isn't a good idea, to say the least. You may read some more on this subject [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=252).

I'm pretty sure that is why you are experiencing problems. Try rearranging the code so that does not happen. You can take a look at some suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023927/java-alternative-to-passing-this-as-constructor-argument-in-order-to-referenc) of how to work around these kinds of situations.

Comment: That is what I suspected, but did not have idea for workaround. I will try to change that

Comment: Ok so after not much succes I resigned from createPhysics in constructor and just use it after inicializing Kapsel like 'code'Kapsel kapsel = new Kapsel(...) and then kapsel.createphysics(physicsworld). But it still do not work. Maybe the problem is actually in onAreaTouched method?

Comment: Looks like the priblem is in onAreaTouched method since when I remove body it still do not work.